# How do you prevent output from being generated in Go until all error checks have completed?

Tags: templates, error-handling, go, buffer

Probably a simple question, but I am having issues delaying the output in a request handler function.  I'm using "bufio" to write to when I execute my templates instead of the response writer, but it seems like the buffer can only hold so much before it spits things out. I'm concerned that it will spit out part of the page, then encounter an error, leaving an incomplete and unintelligible response.  What is the best strategy for ensuring that everything stays buffered until it's ready to be released into the wild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to completely buffer the output use `bytes.Buffer` instead, example:

```
var bufferPool = &sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return &bytes.Buffer{}
    },
}

func getBuffer() (buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    return bufferPool.Get().(*bytes.Buffer)
}

func putBuffer(buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    buf.Reset()
    bufferPool.Put(buf)
}


func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    buf := getBuffer()
    defer putBuffer(buf)
    //....
    fmt.Fprintf(buf, .....)
    buf.WriteTo(w)
}
```

Comment: To reuse the memory of the `Buffer`, you could [do what CloudFlare did](http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go) (put old buffers in a channel, and use buf.Reset() to make the buffer ready for reuse); if you're on the latest version of Go, you can also now make the process prettier with [sync.Pool](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool).

Comment: @twotwotwo there ya go ;)

Comment: Haha, awesome! I was just leaving the tip for the asker to maybe follow up on, but great to have a fully tuned up example searchable on SO.

Comment: This is such a nice example for `sync.Pool`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a bytes.Buffer

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tmp, err := template.New("hello").Parse("Hello {{.World}}")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error", 500)
        return
    }

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    if err := tmp.Execute(buf, map[string]string{"World": "World"}); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error", 500)
        return
    }

    w.Write(buf.Bytes())
}
```